# On the density function of the sum of two random variables

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-distributions, random-variables

Referring to [this exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3710090/question-about-the-ratio-of-two-random-variables).

I'm trying to calculate the distribution of $X+Y$, using the following:
$$p_{X+Y}(z)=\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}p_{X,Y}(x,z-x)=\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{e^{-1}}{3(x-1)!}\mathbb{1}_{\{-x,0,x\}}(z-x)$$
Now, because of the indicator function, we must distinguish 3 cases: $z=0,\ x=z,\ x=z/2$.
In the first case, all the members of the sum are nonzero, so:
$$p_{X+Y}(0)=\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{e^{-1}}{3(x-1)!}=\dfrac{1}{3}$$
Moreover, if $z$ is odd, then $p_{X+Y}(z)=\dfrac{e^{-1}}{3(z-1)!}$, while if $z$ is even then $p_{X+Y}(z)=\dfrac{e^{-1}}{3(z/2-1)!}+\dfrac{e^{-1}}{3(z-1)!}$. Is that correct? I mean, I'm trying to check that the sum of all the values of $p_{X+Y}(z)$ is equal to $1$. So, I have to demonstrate that for $z \ge 1$ the total sum is $2/3$. Also:
$$\sum_{z=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{e^{-1}}{3(x-1)!}=\dfrac{1}{3}$$
So the remaining third is equal to the sum on even numbers of $\dfrac{e^{-1}}{3(z/2-1)!}$? How do I prove it (if it's right)?

Comment: If you sum over even $z$, replace it by $y=\frac{z}{2}$ and sum over $y$.